# Need help with strange Class#getResource() issue

Tags: java, ant

I have some legacy code that reads a configuration file from an existing jar, like:

```
URL url = SomeClass.class.getResource("/configuration.properties");
// some more code here using url variable
InputStream in = url.openStream();
```

Obviously it worked before but when I execute this code, the URL is valid but I get an IOException on the third line, saying it can't find the file. The url is something like "`file:jar:c:/path/to/jar/somejar.jar!configuration.properties`" so it doesn't look like a classpath issue - java knows pretty well where the file can be found..

The above code is part of an ant task and it fails while the task is executed.

Strange enough - I copied the code and the jar file into a separate class and it works as expected, the properties file is readable.

At some point I changed the code of the ant task to

```
URL url = SomeClass.class.getResource("/configuration.properties");
// some more code here using url variable
InputStream in = SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/configuration.properties");
```

and now it works - just until it crashes in another class where a similiar access pattern is implemented..

Why could it have worked before, why does it fail now? The only difference I see at the moment is, that the old build was done with java 1.4 while I'm trying it with Java 6 now.

**Workaround**

Today I installed Java 1.4.2_19 on the build server and made ant to use it. To my totally frustrating surprise: The problem is gone. It looks to me, that java 1.4.2 can handle URLs of this type while Java 1.6 can't (at least in my context/environment).

I'm still hoping for an explanation although I'm facing the work to rewrite parts of the code to use Class#getRessourceAsStream which behaved much more stable...

Comment: If you can debug it, it would be interesting to see what's doing Java. With Eclipse executing the server, some breakpoints and sniffing into the Java classes code maybe you can get something (or just a headache if URL code is complicated enough :). Any way the Class#getResourceAsStream seems more straight-forward and agnostic of the environment.

Comment: Yes, I have to debug. Headache inclusive, because the problem only appears in that hudson triggered ant build on the build server... But it should be possible to connect a remote debugging session to that ant build from an eclipse - I'll keep you informed on the progress ;)

Comment: If you want to debug it, you should probably start with printing `SomeClass.class.getClassLoader()` Who knows, they may be different.

Answer (score 2):

A typical implementation of `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` is:

```
public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String name) {
    URL url = getResource(name);
    try {
        return url != null ? url.openStream() : null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

`Class.getResource` and `getResourceAsStream` behave the same as each other.

So it looks like either you are using a strange and broken subclass of `ClassLoader`, or there is some mistake in the tests on your side.

Comment: Good hint - now that I have two jdks installed I'll have a look at the implementations in both versions. Maybe that leads to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It works with getresourceasstream because it is in the classpath, but it doesn't work with the URL maybe because the URL is not ok.

I don't know if the URL that getResource is creating is not ok, or there isn't a correct handler for the protocol (wouldn't it be `file:jar:c:/myjar.jar!configuration.properties` or something by the like (with two colons?)

Comment: My Java6 runtime prints `jar:file:/C:/Archivos%20de%20programa/Java/jdk1.6.0_14/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/util/ArrayList.class` when I ask for Class.getResource("/java/util/ArrayList.class"). It's the correct format I think.

Comment: thx for the correct URL format - I wasn't able to look it up correctly when writing this question ;) But that's not the problem. It must have worked before and the snippet works with the same library in a 'standalone context' (iaw some dummy class with a main method)

Comment: I'm thinking about a permissions problem. It's really a weird problem :)

Answer (score 1):

use urlConnection.setUseCaches(false), since it's an ant task, it's likely not to be forked in a separate process. The URLs cache the files (or the JarFile in that case)... if the files is change due to the build, you get quite a similar behavior.

you may want to close the modified jar files meanwhile useCaches(true), JarURLConnection.getJarFile().close()

Sometime I wish handling of Jar/Zip was a little better

cheers

Comment: Could have been the issue - I had this problem one year ago and don't maintain the project anymore - Could have been, that the jar file was created/changed during the same build "session". Unfortunatly I can't test and verify but a strong +1 for this answer! (BTW, would it explain why it worked with old java versions?)

Comment: @Andreas_D: >>BTW, would it explain why it worked with old java versions?<<
I don't know now, it was over 6 years I used 1.4.2, will have to download and check the source code of (probably during the weekend)

Answer (score 0):

There are bugs in several Java versions when using file URLs containing spaces. "/path/to/jar" is probably not your real path, so I at least assume that this is what you're running into. Your code is at least in theory ok.

Comment: Thanks, but not an issue here - the path doesn't contain spaces.

Comment: Why don't you post the exact URL and the exact exception which is thrown (not just "something like"). Perhaps then, someone is able to help you?

Comment: The code is disclosed so I do not paste anything to the internet. Although it would be easier, because now I have to invent examples to explain my problems. Spaces was a guess, not a bad guess, but believe me, if the path had had spaces, I would have had investigated in that area or mentioned that fact in the question.